# What configuration is better to parallel two 5 V SMPS?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, parallel

I'm designing a small 5 V SMPS which I want to use in a 5 V parallel configuration. I want to use OR-ing diodes, but these give me a drop of 0.2-0.4 V. I came up with a better solution, but I don't have experience with this one.

Below you see two buck converters. In SMPS[A] I have put the OR-ing diode in series with the output and in SMPS[B] I have put the OR-ing diode before the FB resistor network.

SMPS[B] does not suffer from the 0.2-0.4 V voltage drop. However, in case the input voltage of B is zero the FB pin will have a voltage of around the FB voltage of 0.8 V.

Assuming that both SMPS[A] and [B] have input power the combinations A-A, A-B and B-B should work without a problem.

Assuming that SMPS[A] has input power, SMPS[B] has no power, and [B] is switched on after some time.
The combinations A-A and B-B will work, but the combination A-B I have my doubts about.

If B is powerless and has 0.8 V at its feedback pin and then starts up, will that not generate trouble like latch-up or some other issues I'm not aware of?

Does anyone has experience with this and can tell me if there are things I need to consider?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to use (A) to completely isolate the two SMPSes.

If you use (B), the two FB networks are both fed from a single source. If SMPS A is set to a slightly higher voltage than SMPS B, then SMPD B will perceive it's output (actually SMPS A's output) as too high and try to reduce it's output voltage but will see no change. This will probably cause it to shut down or at least reduce its voltage to minimum. If SMPS A suddenly shuts down, SMPS B will not be able to increase its voltage fast enough to prevent a voltage dip to the consumer.

Also, if only one SMPS is powered, the other one will sill get voltage on its FB input. Applying voltage to an input pin of an unpowered chip is generally a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was afraid for that. I did realize the shutdown response of B when it gets a slight higher output voltage from A but I did not realize the startup time to take over when A disappears. About Applying voltage to an input pin of an unpowered chip is generally a bad thing. I wonder if that accounts to op amp inputs which are often powered by sensors before being powered itself. But I agree with the genera rule not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Took some time, but here is another solution based on a LM393 or lm339 comparator. The switching window is 10mV, which is the difference between the two supply voltages to select one of the two power supplies. Within this window, both power supplies work in parallel outside the window, only one power supply works.
The three figures show the various states the ORing can be in.

Fig 1 shows the ORing when both power supplies are equal. Both power supplies then supply current. In fig 2,3 you can see that with a difference of 10 mV between the power supplies, one or the other is selected.

Let me know if you have suggestion to improve this ORing

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who are interested,

I did some experiments with a circuit that I found on the Internet and it works quite well.
The voltage window in which this switch is working is 150mV difference in output voltage of the two power supplies. Within this window, both power supplies supply a portion of the power. Outside this window only one of the two does, the one with the highest voltage. The picture show the edge of the window in which around 12mA is supplied by the left power supply. With the right voltage at 5.16V the left current is practically zero.

[image]